# How can I use Log4J on Apache Camel CXF?

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf

I create a Soap-Service like:

```
from("cxf://"+WebserviceHost+"SOAP/v2/Webservice?serviceClass=de.Webservice&dataFormat=POJO&loggingFeatureEnabled=true&loggingSizeLimit=-1&synchronous=true")
```

I get the Inbound Message and Outbound Message logged in the Console, but not on Log4J in the Log-File. What should I do, to get it in the Log-File?

I found on google only, that I should create a file META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.logger. But this don't work.